# Having error in FUN when merging datasets in R

Tags: r

I was trying to merge to different data.frame cosponsors and control, by two variables ICPSR and session. I keep the the message Error in FUN. Why does this happen? This is the two data looks like. What should I fix to merge these two datasets?

```
> str(cosponsors)
'data.frame':   2242 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ ICPSR      : num  1077 2605 2605 2605 2605 ...
 $ session    : num  103 103 104 105 106 107 103 103 103 103 ...
 $  dv         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ cd103      : num  4809 2616 2616 2616 2616 ...
 $ dem        : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 ...
 $ rep        : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 ...
 $ indep      : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ dw_nominate: num  -0.44 -0.425 -0.424 -0.422 -0.421 -0.419 0.345 -0.355 -0.378 -0.32 ...
 $ iv         : num  0.262 0.229 0.229 0.229 0.229 ...
 $ yeaprop    : num  0.25 0.25 1 0.571 0.4 ...
> str(control)
'data.frame':   2203 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ session: num  103 103 103 103 103 103 103 103 103 103 ...
 $ ICPSR  : num  1077 2605 6455 6845 8080 ...
 $ evcent : num  0.0109 0.0189 0.039 0.0105 0.0673 0 0.000836 0.0706 0.0882 0.0517 ...
> check<-merge(cosponsors, control, by("session", "ICPSR"))
Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some kind of a typo. you used by as function instead of the argument name

try

```
check<-merge(cosponsors, control, by = c("session", "ICPSR"))
```